# Custom configuration for redis container

Tags: docker, redis, containers

I want to adapt my redis settings via custom conf file and followed the documentation for the implementation. Running my container with the following command throws no error - so far so good.

```
docker run --name redis-container --net redis -v .../redis:/etc/redis -d redis redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

To check if my config file is read I switched the default `port 6379` to `port 6380` but looking at my docker ports via `docker ps` shows the default 6379 as my port.
Is there a difference between the redis port itself and the container port or where is my problem located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Redis image Dockerfile contains the line

```sh
EXPOSE 6379
```

Once a port has been exposed this way, there is no way to un-expose it.  Exposing a port has fairly few practical effects in modern Docker, but the most visible is that `6379/tcp` will show up in the `docker ps` output for each exposed port even if it's not separately published (`docker run -p`).  There's no way to remove this port number from the `docker ps` output.

Docker's port system (the `EXPOSE` directive and the `docker run -p` option) are a little bit disconnected from what the application inside the container is actually doing.  In your case the container is configured to expose port 6379 but the process is actually listening on port 6380; Docker has no way of knowing these don't match up.  Changing the application configuration won't change the container configuration, and *vice versa*.

As a practical matter you don't usually need to change application ports.  Since this Redis will be the only thing running in its container and its corresponding isolated network namespace, it can't conflict with other Redises on the host or in other containers.  If you need to remap it on the host, you can use different port numbers for `-p`; the second number must match what the process is listening on (and Docker can't auto-detect or check this) but the first can be any port.

```sh
docker run -p 6380:6379 ... redis
```

If you're trying to check whether your configuration has had an effect, running [`CONFIG GET`](https://redis.io/commands/config-get) via `redis-cli` could be a more direct way to ask what the server's configuration is.